# How to wake-up/resume after calling SetSystemPowerState in WINCE 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, bsp

We are currently changing the state of our device to suspend using SetSystemPowerState(NULL, POWER_STATE_SUSPEND, POWER_FORCE) so we can save power when the system is not acquiring any readings. The problem is that after suspending the device using SetSystemPowerState in our application, we are not able to wake it up with a touch in screen, home key or interrupt signal. How we can set the system up to wake up on a touch screen event or interrupt signal? Do we have to modify the registers?

We are currently using WINCE 7 and VS 2008. Our processor is an iMX53.

Thanks!